# DBUnit duplicate rows removal

Tags: unit-testing, testng, dbunit

Need to know how to remove duplicate rows in dataset .
I am gathering data from two different databases (all columns are same in both of them) and they have some same rows.

I use `QueryDataSet` two times. I merge them by using `CompositeDataSet`.
Thing I get is list of all rows and some of them are duplicate.

Is there an easy way to delete those duplicates and to order them somehow? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: At least for ordering this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142365/db-unit-should-ignore-order-of-rows might help you.