# SprigngTestDBUnit. How to ignore row order when comparing expected and actual datasets

Tags: spring, junit4, spring-test-dbunit

I'm using com.github.springtestdbunit to conduct persistence tests on my DAO layer. The problem is that i don't know in which order data will be saved to database, so i need to ignore row order when comparing expected and actual datasets.
Basically it's the same issue [DB Unit should ignore order of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142365/db-unit-should-ignore-order-of-rows) but i wonder how to fix it without hacking a library's @ExpectedDatabase annotation and its enum parameter DatabaseAssertionMode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess it will be fixed soon with unordered assertion mode https://github.com/springtestdbunit/spring-test-dbunit/pull/48